# Fetching image using xpath or some other way

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, getattribute

I need to fetch the image from a remote page, i tried xpath but i was told it wont work because img does not have nodevalue
Then i was advised to use getAttribute, but i dont know how to get it working.

Any suggestions?
This is my code

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

//Setting content type to xml!
header('Content-type: application/xml');

//POST Field name is bWV0aG9k

$url_prefix = $_GET['bWV0aG9k'];

$url_http_request_encode = strpos($url_prefix, "http://");


//Checking to see if url has a http prefix
if($url_http_request_encode === false){
    //does not have, add it!
    $fetchable_url_link_consistancy_remote_data = "http://".$url_prefix;

}
else
    //has it, do nothing
{
   $fetchable_url_link_consistancy_remote_data = $url_prefix;
}



//Creating a new DOM Document on top of pre-existing one 
$page = new DOMDocument();

//Loading the requested file
$page->loadHTMLFile($fetchable_url_link_consistancy_remote_data);

//Initliazing xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($page);

//Search parameters 

//Searching for title attribute
$query = "//title";
//Searching for paragraph attribute
$query1 = "//p";
//Searching for thumbnails
$query2 = "//img";


//Binding the attributes to xpath for later use
$title = $xpath->query($query);

$paragraph = $xpath->query($query1);

$images = $xpath->query($query2);




echo "<remotedata>";
//Echoing the attributes
echo "<title-render>".$title->item(0)->nodeValue."</title-render>";
echo "<paragraph>".$paragraph->item(0)->nodeValue."</paragraph>";
echo "<image_link>".$images->item(0)->nodeValue."</image_link>";
echo "</remotedata>";

?>
```

Comment: Hint: Do not use comments to tell what the next line does. `//Setting content type to xml!` is entirely superfluous when the next line says `header('Content-type: application/xml');`. Same thing with all your other comments.

Comment: Apart from that: Without seeing the XML your are dealing with, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: try checkin phpquery... it should help.

Answer (score 1):

you should get source attribute of an image tag.

```
$images->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: Do you suggest i do a getElementByTagName first just to make sure that i get the src of only img tags?

Comment: I assume that you have loaded html in dom.
$query2 = "//img";  // will select all image tags
$images = $xpath->query($query2); // $imags have select all image tags

$images->item(0)->getAttribute('src'); //will give you src attribute value of first image

Answer (score 1):

if this is normal xhtml, img has no value, you need the value of img/@src